# Show upcoming events in the today scope on ubuntu phone

Tags: ubuntu-touch, scopes

I would like to see more upcoming events in my today scope (e.g. all events of this week or the next 5 events).  Is there a way to show more then just the events that are actually today?

Thanks, for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to configure this in the Today scope, which per default seems to display only today's events. You can click on the small arrow on the right side of Events today to get to the upcoming events. Alternatively, you can add the scope Upcoming, that should rather fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to add this to *Today scope*, which shows only *today events*.

When you use *Upcoming events scope*, it will also show *today events* as well as *upcoming events*, but only **up to two days from now** with no settings to change this.